# Can I get "disk utilization" from a NetApp filer via SNMP?

Tags: snmp, netapp

On a NetApp filer's command line I'm running "sysstat -u" to show disk utilization, (actually the utilization of the single busiest disk). By disk utilization, I mean "percent of time the disk is busy", not "how much space on the disk is being used to store data/metadata".

Is there a way to get disk utilization info through SNMP? The netapp.mib file doesn't appear to expose this. It does have CPU utilization, disk usage & capacity information, etc, but not disk utilization. The MIB-II (rfc1213) seems to be the only other information exposed by the filer through SNMP. I hope I am missing something.

The "CP (consistency point) time" metric is exposed through the NETAPP-MIB in SNMP, but this seems to only partially correlate with disk utilization under write load, and not really at all under read load.

Comment: What version are you on? and what model?

Comment: It's an IBM N3300, which I believe is a rebranded NetApp FAS2020. The software version is Data ONTAP Release 7.3.3.

Comment: Just checked, you're right, no support at all for that, odd, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk utilization as reported by sysstat is not exposed through SNMP.

Answer (score 0):

If they support the [HOST-RESOURCES-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790), that's the standard place for reporting disk partitioning information.  But, it'll only work if they actually support it.

Comment: `snmpwalk -c public -v1 <host> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystem` gives the expected result when host is a solaris box, but no output is generated when host is the filer. Looks like HOST-RESOURCES-MIB is not supported. Thanks, though.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately it looks like there is no answer you're going to like then :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can get it via SSH using a `bash` script. This example script is named `netapp.diskutil`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1 -l root 'sysstat -c1 -u' | tail -n1 | rev | cut -d " "  -f1 | rev | cut -d "%" -f1
```

An example using the script:

```
# ./netapp.diskutil netapp1
12
```

You have to set up key authentication for this to work.